# vuetify v-radio doesn't select one radio in table nuxt js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-table, nuxt.js

so i try to make a multiple grid radio with condition it select one radio button and save it as json with key: question and value: column where the radio buttoin selected

```
<template>
    <v-radio-group class="mt-0" v-model="answer" :rules="answerRule">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Pilihan</th>
                <th v-for="(option, keys) in columns" :key="keys + 'A'">
                    {{ option.value }}
                </th>
            </tr>

               <tr v-for="(option, keys) in rowsCols" :key="keys + 'C'">
                <th>{{ option.value }}</th>
                <td
                    v-for="(optioncol, keys) in option.columns"
                    :key="keys + 'B'"
                >
                    <v-radio-group
                        v-model="answer"
                        @change="update"
                        :rules="answerRule"
                    >
                        <v-radio
                            class="radioA"
                            solo
                            v-bind:key="option.id"
                            :value="optioncol"
                        >
                        </v-radio>
                    </v-radio-group>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </v-radio-group>
</template>
```

here how it looks in the browser but it selected all row
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
here is my script on how to load the data and try to save the json...

```
export default {
    props: ['question'],
    data() {
        return {
            rows: this.question.options,
            answer: [],
            columns: this.question.optionsColumns,
            answerRule: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async update() {
            try {
                let payload = {
                    questionId: this.question.id,
                    value: this.answer,
                    questionName: this.question.question,
                }

                //update question options
                await this.$store.commit('answers/update', payload)
            } catch (err) {
                this.$store.commit('alerts/show', {
                    type: 'error',
                    message: err.response
                        ? this.$t(err.response.data.message)
                        : this.$t('SERVER_ERROR'),
                })
            }
        },
    },
    beforeMount() {
        if (this.question.required) {
            this.answerRule.push(
                (v) => v.length > 0 || this.$t('QUESTION_REQUIRED')
            )
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Any help on that? because i've try and still cannot figure it out

Here is the Data that i already change into new format :

```
row:[{id:1,value:"asdasd",columns:[a,b,c]},{id:2,value:"asdasd",columns:[a,b,c]}{id:3,value:"asdasd"}{id:1,value:"asdasd",columns:[a,b,c]}]
```

yet i still got the same problem
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fsIF.png

Comment: well, the columns in every row are using the same `v-bind:value="option.value"` so of course they will always be the same

Comment: Is there a ways to prevent it..?

Comment: prevent it? you mean use data correctly and fix it ... usually, each row in the data would have an array of columns, so not one separate data for columns, but columns within **each** row

Comment: i have change the structure into rows with column inside the row, but it still wont select only one radio

Comment: your still using `columns` data rather than `row.columns`

Comment: i have change it, just not edited the question

Comment: what's `a,b,c` if they refer to objects, then you haven't changed anything

Comment: I recommending focusing on the structure of your data and be sure on what you need to do with all the array methods before proceeding. More of a vanilla JS issue here, nothing related to Vue/Nuxt so don't stack them together.

Comment: Do not nest `v-radio-group` inside other `v-radio-group`.